# SortedList with string as index and function pointer or delegate as value? And Calling Functions by strings?

Tags: c#, function, delegates, lambda

I'm not familiar with delegates and lambdas but at this moment, I have to do these two things:

- One of them is:

I need to pass the function to SortedList. I don't know how it can be done.

Why I need it, is:

```
private string Func1(string s) { return s + "1"; }
private string Func2(string s) { return s + "2"; }
private string Func3(string s) { return s + "3"; }

private void WhatEver()
{
SortedList<string, ???> list = new SortedList<string, ???>;
list.Add("Func1", Func1);
list.Add("Func2", Func2);
list.Add("Func3", Func3);

// And after that I have to pass values and get results from functions
// Like

Console.WriteLine(list["Func1"]("Test"));
Console.WriteLine(list["Func2"]("Test"));
Console.WriteLine(list["Func3"]("Test"));

// Output should be:
//
// Test1
// Test2
// Test3

}
```

- Second:

Is it possible to call functions with strings?

Ex:

Let's say I've got three textboxes and a function:

```
tbFunction
tbArgument
tbResult

private string Test(string number)
{
    int x = int.Parse(number);
    return (x * x).ToString();
}
```

Let's say I've got "Test" in tbFunction.Text and "2" in tbArgument.Text, How Can I bring the result to tbResult.Text

Comment: I honestly have no idea what you're trying to do in the first part of this question.  Drop the implementation-specific details about passing functions to a SortedList and just say what you're trying to accomplish, please? -- Also, it looks like you're trying to do something like a Dictionary, not a SortedList...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It took a while to figure out what you wanted.  So, if I follow you correctly, you want:

- Given the name of a method in a string variable, call than method.

The simple answer is that there is no intrinsic means of doing that.  You could probably cobble together something using Reflection, but it would be more efforts than it's worth.

So, we'll need to create our own dispatch table:

```
// class member
var jumptbl = new SortedList<string, Func<string, string> >();

 // :  (in ctor)
jumptbl.Add("Test", Test);

// :  (I'm guessing this is in a Click handler)
tbResult.Text = jumptbl[tbFunction.Text](tbArgument.Text)
```

Carrying this further, the name (in the string) used to call it need not have any connection to the name of the function itself.  The method doesn't even have to have a name:

```
jumptbl.Add("Func1", s=> s + "1");
jumptbl.Add("Func2", s=> s + "2");
jumptbl.Add("Func3", s=> s + "3");
```

Comment: What should I declare in second argument of list as value type?

Comment: @haxxoromer: "Func<string, string>" which is a delegate  which takes a string and return a string.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a job for reflection, has nothing to do with lambdas or delegates.

You will need to do something like...

```
MethodInfo method = typeof(ClassWithMethods).GetMethod(tbFunction.Text);
ClassWithMethods obj = new ClassWithMethods();
string result = method.Invoke(obj, new[] {tbArgument.Text});
tbResult.Text = result;
```

Check around in the System.Reflection documentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
public delegate string YourDelegate(string number);
SortedList<string, YourDelegate> methods = new SortedList<string, YourDelegate>();

// Add more methods here
methods .Add("Test", Test);
...

public string CallMethod(string methodName, string number)
{
    YourDelegate method;
    if (methods.TryGetValue(methodName, out method))
        return method(number);
    else
        return "Unknown method";
}
...

public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tbResult.Text = CallMethod(tbFunction.Text, tbArgument.Text);
}
```

I think that this is just about what you are asking for.
Personally I would use Dictinary but that is probably just a matter of taste.

Alternatively you could use reflection, that way you would not need to register each method in a list.